# Multiple duplicate questions by the same user

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I noticed that this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6666678/prasanth-p) has asked a set of duplicate question, some asked just couple of hours apart.

These are a set of duplicates:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930477/how-to-change-the-graph-in-quadratic-based-on-equation
- [How to draw the graph using two input x and y value using js library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911116/how-to-draw-the-graph-using-two-input-x-and-y-value-using-js-library)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932961/how-show-the-graph-in-full-green-in-math-js
- [How to shown in graph both axis in full screen using math.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971543/how-to-shown-in-graph-both-axis-in-full-screen-using-math-js)

and so are these:

- [how to extract the snapshot using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990756/how-to-extract-the-snapshot-using-js)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993659/how-to-programming-the-download-in-div-tag-using-js

And it's the same case for a few others of his questions.

What is the procedure of handling this scenario?

Comment: I've taken the liberty to close all the newer questions as duplicates of the oldest 2. In the future, as a start, close-voting them as duplicates will help.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the liberty to close all the newer questions as duplicates of the oldest 2.

In the future, as a start, close-voting them as duplicates will help. Eventually, users that post content like this will be question-banned, due to the amount of closed questions they own.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that for any other such occurrence